# Nodepool in AKS not scaling down to 0 nodes?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

I have two nodepools in my AKS cluster; the default nodepool and an 'application' nodepool. I use the default nodepool for services like Airflow, and the application nodepool to run ETL jobs. However, the application nodepool never scales to zero, even when I do not schedule any ETL jobs for many hours.

I fail to understand why. Is there anyone who has any suggestions for the rootcause of the issue?

The cluster is depolyed using Terraform. The autoscaler is configured as foloows:

```
auto_scaler_profile {
    # (Optional) Maximum number of seconds the cluster autoscaler waits for pod termination when trying to scale down a node. Defaults to 600.
    max_graceful_termination_sec = 180
    # (Optional) How long after the scale up of AKS nodes the scale down evaluation resumes. Defaults to 10m.)
    scale_down_delay_after_add = "3m"
    # - (Optional) How long a node should be unneeded before it is eligible for scale down. Defaults to 10m.
    scale_down_unneeded = "3m"
    # (Optional) If true cluster autoscaler will never delete nodes with pods from kube-system (except for DaemonSet or mirror pods). Defaults to true.
    skip_nodes_with_system_pods = false
  }
```

and the application nodepool is defined as:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "main" {
  name                  = "application"
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.id
  vm_size               = "Standard_B4ms"
  enable_auto_scaling   = true
  min_count             = 0
  max_count             = 2
  max_pods              = 15

  node_labels = {
    "type" = "application"
  }

}
```

---

Below are some relevant details about the AKS cluster:

```bash
k top nodes

NAME                                  CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000   55m          1%     1579Mi          12%       
aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000       677m         17%    7783Mi          61%
```

```bash
az aks nodepool show \
--resource-group <my-rg> \
--cluster-name <my-cluster> \
--name application \
--query "{min: minCount, max: maxCount}"

{
  "max": 2,
  "min": 0
}
```

```bash
az aks show \
--resource-group <my-rg> \
--name <my-cluster> \
--query autoScalerProfile

{
  "balanceSimilarNodeGroups": "false",
  "expander": "random",
  "maxEmptyBulkDelete": "10",
  "maxGracefulTerminationSec": "180",
  "maxNodeProvisionTime": "15m",
  "maxTotalUnreadyPercentage": "45",
  "newPodScaleUpDelay": "0s",
  "okTotalUnreadyCount": "3",
  "scaleDownDelayAfterAdd": "3m",
  "scaleDownDelayAfterDelete": "10s",
  "scaleDownDelayAfterFailure": "3m",
  "scaleDownUnneededTime": "3m",
  "scaleDownUnreadyTime": "20m",
  "scaleDownUtilizationThreshold": "0.5",
  "scanInterval": "10s",
  "skipNodesWithLocalStorage": "true",
  "skipNodesWithSystemPods": "false"
}
```

```bash
k get pods  --sort-by="{.spec.nodeName}" -A -o wide                                                                                                          
NAMESPACE      NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     NODE                                 
kube-system    azure-ip-masq-agent-XXXXX             1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    metrics-server-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX       2/2     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    metrics-server-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX       2/2     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    kube-proxy-XXXXX                      1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    csi-blob-node-XXXXX                   3/3     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    csi-azurefile-node-XXXXX              3/3     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    csi-azuredisk-node-XXXXX              3/3     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    cloud-node-manager-XXXXX              1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-application-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    cloud-node-manager-XXXXX              1/1     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
airflow-prod   airflow-pgbouncer-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX    2/2     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
airflow-prod   airflow-triggerer-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXX     1/1     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
airflow-prod   airflow-webserver-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXX     1/1     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
airflow-prod   airflow-scheduler-XXXXXXXXX-XXXXX     2/2     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    azure-ip-masq-agent-XXXXX             1/1     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
airflow-prod   airflow-postgresql-0                  1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    coredns-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX              1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    coredns-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX              1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    coredns-autoscaler-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX   1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
airflow-prod   airflow-statsd-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX         1/1     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    csi-azuredisk-node-XXXXX              3/3     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    csi-azurefile-node-XXXXX              3/3     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    csi-blob-node-XXXXX                   3/3     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    konnectivity-agent-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX   1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    konnectivity-agent-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX   1/1     Running   0          3d17h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
kube-system    kube-proxy-XXXXX                      1/1     Running   0          3d21h   aks-default-XXXXXXXX-vmss000000
```

[image]

Comment: When you manually scale down the pool to zero, does it work or does it complain?  az aks nodepool scale --name <your node pool name> --cluster-name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup  --node-count 0

Comment: Thanks, that is a good suggestion to give a try! However, apparently that is not allowed on nodepools where the autoscaler is enabled: `Cannot scale cluster autoscaler enabled node pool.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, adding a dedicated system node pool did not resolve the issue. Initially the `metrics-server` pods were moved to the new node pool, but they ended up in the `application` node pool again later, after which the `application` nodepool would not scale down to 0 anymore. I believe that is because they had this volume attached:

```
Volumes:
  tmp-dir:
    Type:       EmptyDir
```

The autoscaler documentation for the argument `skip_nodes_with_local_storage` reads:

> (Optional) If true cluster autoscaler will never delete nodes with pods with local storage, for example, EmptyDir or HostPath. Defaults to true.

So I added the following to my autoscaler configuration in Terraform:

```
  auto_scaler_profile {
    # (Optional) If true cluster autoscaler will never delete nodes with pods from kube-system (except for DaemonSet or mirror pods). Defaults to true.
    # metrics server is not Daemonset, so will not allow scale down.
    skip_nodes_with_system_pods = false
    # (Optional) If true cluster autoscaler will never delete nodes with pods with local storage, for example, EmptyDir or HostPath. Defaults to true.
    skip_nodes_with_local_storage = false
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some system pods block node removal because there is no node affinity on your system pods.

You can remedy this by deploying a dedicated system node pool.

Comment: I was also going to suggest this. I've only ever done "scale to zero" when using a dedicated system pool.  Here's a e2e sample i wrote that has 3 user pools that all scale from/to 0. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/selenium-grid-aks-keda

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am not sure I understand it 100% though. In Azure, the default nodepool is a system nodepool by default. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-system-pools?tabs=azure-cli). Is this what you refer to a a "dedicated system node pool"? Shouldn't this, in combination with the option `skip_nodes_with_system_pods = false`, allow for `kube-system` pods to be removed or moved to the default node(pool)?

Comment: i've never tried this, but given my aks experience i'd imagine it cant scale down to 0 nodes if there are no other nodes in the cluster. you have `aks stop` for that

Comment: Thanks for the comment @4c74356b41. In this scenario however there is a node left; only the 'application' nodepool should scale to 0, the default (system) nodepool remains intact and exists of 1 node.

Comment: check that there are no system pods on that pool

Comment: Can you try setting the minimum number of nodes to 2 in the "default" node pool?

Comment: Thanks! It seemed that indeed adding a dedicated system node pool solved the issue. I think my confusion was that the default node pool is not a 'dedicated' node pool, since it also allows other pods to be scheduled on it. Creating a node pool with taint `"CriticalAddonsOnly=true:NoSchedule"` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize or delete a user node pool after cordoning and draining nodes in the pool like explained in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/resize-node-pool?tabs=azure-cli#cordon-the-existing-nodes):

```
kubectl cordon aks-nodepool1-xxxxxxx-vmss000000 aks-nodepool1-xxxxxxx-vmss000001 
kubectl drain aks-nodepool1-xxxxxxx-vmss000000 aks-nodepool1-xxxxxxx-vmss000001 --ignore-daemonsets --delete-emptydir-data
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I see that this could work to scale down the node pool manually occasionally, but in my scenario I want the node pool to scale down to 0 automatically regularly.